# Mongodb database dropped automatically

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm newbie to mongodb, my mongodb database was getting dropped automatically sometimes. I could not find the cause. We have not issued any drop command . but the database is missing and log file contains,

**MongoDB - Version 2.4.6**

```
dropDatabase test starting
removeJournalFiles
dropDatabase test finished
Assertion: 13347:local.oplog.rs missing. did you drop it? if so restart server
0x9877f6 0x94bfaa 0x7998e8 0x794d8c 0x6b909e 0x6b95bc 0x7a1549 0x7a4b03 0x75a530 0x5a08eb 0x973c82 0x33b8e07f33 0x33b86f4ded 
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x26) [0x9877f6]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x9a) [0x94bfaa]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0x7998e8]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo5logOpEPKcS1_RKNS_7BSONObjEPS2_Pbb+0x3c) [0x794d8c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPS0_RNS_6ClientEiPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xb6e) [0x6b909e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x22c) [0x6b95bc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_5CurOpERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x29) [0x7a1549]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERNS_5CurOpES1_+0x6c3) [0x7a4b03]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x6f0) [0x75a530]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0xbb) [0x5a08eb]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x432) [0x973c82]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x33b8e07f33]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x33b86f4ded]
```

Please anyone explain me the cause of automatic DB dropping .

Comment: Have you enabled authentication and properly secured your MongoDB deployment? The likely cause of "automatic dropping" is an unsecured deployment. The solution would be to implement the security measures outlined on the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) (enable access control & user authentication, limit network exposure, etc). I would also note that MongoDB 2.4 is a very old and unsupported version of MongoDB (released in Aug, 2013). I strongly recommend upgrading to a supported version (latest is MongoDB 3.4).

Comment: @Stennie Database dropped will be due to this http://www.pcworld.com/article/3155258/security/more-than-10000-exposed-mongodb-databases-deleted-by-ransomware-groups.html ?